# 'Could you please share [or xyz task]'—with or without question mark?

Tags: phrase-requests, punctuation, writing-style, questions, question-mark

Often, the type of sentence I have in mind, though interrogative in form, comes with a sense of being an order, not a refusable request, and people have stopped using a question mark at the end of such a sentence.

For example, your boss (or some other respected person such as a grandparent or parent) might not use a question mark, because they are actually not giving you the option to say "no". But when the situation reverses, would it be right to use a question mark? Would using a question mark bring a sense of rudeness? If so, how might the person put it correctly?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include an example sentence, with and without the question mark(?).

Comment: If you are asking a question, use a question mark.  It's really that simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, the absence of a question mark in a sentence otherwise structured as a question indicates the speaker's or writer's expectation that the person or persons addressed will cooperate with or acquiesce in or obey the instruction being given. *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003) refers to expressions of this type as "courtesy questions" and offers the following advice on how to punctuate them:

> **6.74** *Courtesy question.* A request courteously disguised as a question does not require a question mark.
>
> [Examples:] Would you kindly respond by March 1. [and] Will the audience please rise.

But "courtesy question" is a bit of a misnomer, since these statements are really something closer to "courtesy demands": The speaker or writer expects that you will perform the requested action and expresses the request in the form of a question only out of politeness.

It seems to me that adding a question mark to this type of question invites (that is to say, accepts the possibility of) a negative response in a way that ending it with a period does not. Therefore, when you are dealing with someone who has greater authority or a greater claim to deference than you do—an employer, say, or a parent—it makes sense to include the question mark simply as a token that you are not arrogating to yourself the right to tell that other person what to do.

Under the circumstances, your concern that "using a question mark [might] bring a sense of rudeness" seems unfounded, since posing the request as a real question (and not as a "courtesy question") is logically a sign of respect, not of rudeness.

Answer (score 1):

As I do not have enough reputation to put a comment below your question, I write my opinions as an "answer".

I firmly believe that it highly depends on the *office culture*, and *business ethic*. Most of the time, there is a hierarchy between the boss and colleagues, so it is not abnormal to hear:

> "Please take the necessary actions."

instead of,

> "Could you please take the necessary actions?"

It's not rude, it depends on the fact - **formality**.

I hope this answers your question well.